# Sourcemap for Appium, using Visual Studio Code as debugger?

Tags: appium, source-maps, javascript-debugger, gulp-sourcemaps

I am setting up a debugging environment for [Appium](http://appium.io/), which is a nodejs application with a gulpfile. I am able to run `gulp transpile` which generates .js files in build/lib. Now when it comes to setting breakpoints, I need to set breakpoints in build/lib/*.js rather than the original lib/*.js source files. I installed [gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) and wrote a task to generate sourcemaps which generates .js.map files.

I am stuck after this point. The files generated by `gulp transpile` don't know about these sourcemaps. And I don't want to edit all the generated build files to add `//# sourceMappingURL` manually at the end every time I use `gulp transpile`. So how do I get my editor (Visual Studio code) to use these map files and let me place breakpoints in original source rather than generated build files?

I have looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_node-debugging but can't quite get the debugger to use the source maps generated by gulp using the task I wrote.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
        includeContent: false,
        sourceRoot: '{here your relative URL path to the source dir}'
    }))
```